# Angular2 material dialog has issues - Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to follow the docs on https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog but I cannot understand why it has the below issue?

I added the below on my component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-result-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog-result-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogResultExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogResultExampleDialog>) {}
}
```

In my module I added

```js
import { HomeComponent,DialogResultExampleDialog } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DialogResultExampleDialog
  ],

// ...
```

Yet I get this error....

```js
EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:53:0 caused by: No component factory found for DialogResultExampleDialog. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
    next @ application_ref.js:346
    schedulerFn @ async.js:91
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
    SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
    Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
    NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
    onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
    ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
    Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
    ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
    error_handler.js:52 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No component factory found for DialogResultExampleDialog. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52
    next @ application_ref.js:346
    schedulerFn @ async.js:91
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223
    SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172
    Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125
    Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89
    Subject.next @ Subject.js:55
    EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:77
    NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:329
    onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:290
    ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
    Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
    ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345
```

Answer (score 634, accepted):

**Angular 9.0.0 <**

> Since 9.0.0 with Ivy, the entryComponents property is no longer necessary. See [deprecations guide](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#entrycomponents-and-analyze_for_entry_components-no-longer-required).

**Angular 9.0.0 >**

You need to add dynamically created components to `entryComponents` inside your `@NgModule`

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DialogResultExampleDialog        
  ],
  entryComponents: [DialogResultExampleDialog]
```

**Note:** In some cases `entryComponents` under **lazy loaded modules** will not work, as a workaround put them in your `app.module` (root)

Comment: Every time I fel like I get my head around NgModule something like this comes up and makes you wonder whether this framework needs to be so complex.   At least the error messages helpful though.

Comment: What if you already had them in there? why would it say they arent?

Comment: @SamAlexander your question is really broad as you'd appreciate but taking a wild guess; do you use them inside your lazy loaded module?

Comment: thanks, i actually hadnt put it my main module file, just my directory specific one. That part has been fixed

Comment: dialogs in lazy loaded modules do work as of 2.0.0-beta.2

Comment: @charlie_pl thanks for the update I put the issue as an example, I'll edit it.

Comment: I am unable to import DialogResultExampleDialog, please tell from which library its to be imported?

Comment: This did not work for me. I added my component in the NgModule entryComponents and I still receive the exact same error. I only have one NgModule at this point, if that helps at all.

Comment: @rottenoats can you reproduce the issue in a plunker or give more info about your architecture please :)

Comment: Thanks for the note! It's important in my case that works only adding in entryComponents on the app.module

Comment: What if I can't put my component (DialogResultExampleDialog) in my app.module (root)?

Comment: Just found out that MatDialog.open takes a TemplateRef. This can be used as another workaround for lazy loaded modules.

Comment: my component which calls **ModalComponent** is a grandchild of a component. Neither adding the **ModalComponent** to `entryComponents` nor adding it to `exports` worked for me. **BUT** I can call the **ModalComponent** from some other components which are not grandchilds

Answer (score 53):

You need to use `entryComponents` under `@NgModule`.

This is for dynamically added components that are added using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`. Adding them to entryComponents tells the offline template compiler to compile them and create factories for them.

The components registered in route configurations are added automatically to `entryComponents` as well because `router-outlet` also uses `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` to add routed components to the DOM.

So your code will be like

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DialogResultExampleDialog        
  ],
  entryComponents: [DialogResultExampleDialog]
```

Comment: Ugh... I had two dialogs that were otherwise identical but one I had a test route pointing to it. I removed that test route and sure enough... the routing was "helping" me.  >:(

Comment: @Sunil Garg I have another issue. My dialog show but it automatically close within 1sec. Please help me.

Answer (score 11):

This is happening because this is a **dynamic component** and you didn't add it to `entryComponents` under `@NgModule`.

Simply add it there:

```js
@NgModule({
  /* ----------------- */
  entryComponents: [ DialogResultExampleDialog ] // <---- Add it here
```

Look at how the **Angular team** talks about `entryComponents`:

> `entryComponents?: Array<Type<any>|any[]>` 
> Specifies a list of
>   components that should be compiled when this module is defined. For
>   each component listed here, Angular will create a ComponentFactory and
>   store it in the ComponentFactoryResolver.

Also, this is the list of the methods on `@NgModule` including `entryComponents`...

As you can see, all of them are optional (look at the question marks), including `entryComponents` which accept an array of components:

```js
@NgModule({ 
  providers?: Provider[]
  declarations?: Array<Type<any>|any[]>
  imports?: Array<Type<any>|ModuleWithProviders|any[]>
  exports?: Array<Type<any>|any[]>
  entryComponents?: Array<Type<any>|any[]>
  bootstrap?: Array<Type<any>|any[]>
  schemas?: Array<SchemaMetadata|any[]>
  id?: string
})
```

Comment: same case with me and will not works:

it shows: Error: No component factory found for DialogConfirmComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Any idea?

Comment: You need to insert it into ngAfterViewInit (from @angular/core)

Answer (score 8):

If you're trying to use `MatDialog` inside a service - let's call it `'PopupService'` and that service is defined in a module with:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```

then it may not work. I am using lazy loading, but not sure if that's relevant or not.

You have to:

- Provide your `PopupService` directly to the component that opens your dialog - using `[ provide: PopupService ]`. This allows it to use (with DI) the `MatDialog` instance in the component. I think the component calling `open` needs to be in the same module as the dialog component in this instance.
- Move the dialog component up to your app.module (as some other answers have said)
- Pass a reference for `matDialog` when you call your service.

Excuse my jumbled answer, **the point being it's the `providedIn: 'root'` that is breaking things because MatDialog needs to piggy-back off a component.**

Comment: this happens! indeed add your service to provide instead of looking at entrycomponent, wrong error message!

Comment: Happening the same for me, but I couldn't understand from this answer, which point is the solution ? Or all 3 are required ?

Comment: I had the same issue

Answer (score 4):

In case of lazy loading, you just need to import **MatDialogModule** in lazy loaded module. Then this module will be able to render entry component with its own imported **MatDialogModule**:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:[
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DialogResultExampleDialog        
  ],
  entryComponents: [DialogResultExampleDialog]
```

Answer (score 1):

While integrating material dialog is *possible*, I found that the complexity for such a trivial feature is pretty high. The code gets more complex if you are trying to achieve a non-trivial features.

For that reason, I ended up using [PrimeNG Dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/), which I found pretty straightforward to use:

**`m-dialog.component.html`**:

```html
<p-dialog header="Title">
  Content
</p-dialog>
```

**`m-dialog.component.ts`**:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'm-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'm-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./m-dialog.component.css']
})
export class MDialogComponent {
  // dialog logic here
}
```

**`m-dialog.module.ts`**:

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { DialogModule } from "primeng/primeng";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    DialogModule
  ], 
  exports: [
    MDialogComponent,
  ], 
  declarations: [
    MDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class MDialogModule {}
```

Simply add your dialog into your component's html:

```html
<m-dialog [isVisible]="true"> </m-dialog>
```

[PrimeNG PrimeFaces documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog) is easy to follow and very precise.

Comment: you do not face topic-starter issue only till you do not need dynamic created component. If you try (even with primeng) create dialogservice that use dynamic component creation - you will face exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

You must add it to `entryComponents`, as specified in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code-).

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DialogInvokingComponent, 
    DialogResultExampleDialog
  ],
  declarations: [
    DialogInvokingComponent,   
    DialogResultExampleDialog
  ],
  // ...
})
```

Here is [a full example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/njdkroaomnb?file=main.ts) for an app module file with a dialog defined as `entryComponents`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me, and are staring at this thread thinking "But I'm not trying to add a component, I am trying to add a guard/service/pipe, etc." then the issue is likely that you have added the wrong type to a routing path. That is what I did. I accidentally added a guard to the component: section of a path instead of the canActivate: section. I love IDE autocomplete but you have to slow down a bit and pay attention. If you absolutely can't find it, do a global search for the name it is complaining about and look at every usage to make sure you didn't slip-up with a name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added my component to declarations and entryComponents and got the same errors. I also needed to add MatDialogModule to imports.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs to call Dialog from services here is how to solve the issue.
I agree with some of above answer, my answer is for calling dialog in services if someone may face issues on.

Create a service for example DialogService then move your dialog function inside the services and add your dialogservice in the component you call like below code:

```
 @Component({
  selector: "app-newsfeed",
  templateUrl: "./abc.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./abc.component.css",],
  providers:[DialogService]
})
```

otherwise you get error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and i had dialogComponent in EntryComponents and it still did not work. this is how I was able to solve the problem. the link is here to a previously answered post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64224799/14385758