# MatDialog not displayed correctly

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use a `MatDialog` and based on [this example](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) I've implemented that dialog as follows:

```js
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../../../service/authentication.service';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateGroupDialogComponent);
  }    
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-group-dialog',
  template: `
    <span>Hello World!</span>
  `
})
export class CreateGroupDialogComponent {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateGroupDialogComponent>) {  }
}
```

However, even though the dialog comes up as I press the according button, what I get it this:

[image]

The HTML template gets not displayed and the dimensions of the modal is wrong.

I don't see what the problem is. Why is the modal not correctly drawn?

This is the generated HTML code when opening the modal. As can be seen it's empty.

[image]

Comment: You may need `mat-dialog-content` when you use the `mat-dialog-actions` ref. See https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content

Comment: @flamusdiu I don't think that's a requirement but even if I add it or just display a `<span>Hello World!</span>` it's still the same result.

Comment: what's in your CSS? empty?

Comment: @flamusdiu Yes, no additional CSS involved.

Comment: It looks to think it's a sidenav tab. Let me try it in a new project.

Comment: @flamusdiu Hm, I have a sidenav included which I'm not using atm. I removed it but it's still not working. It's weird that the content is not loaded at all.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to add it to `entryComponents` on your `@NgModule`

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogModule, MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent, DialogOverviewExampleDialogComponent } from './home/home.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DialogOverviewExampleDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    DialogOverviewExampleDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Dup of [Angular2 material dialog has issues - Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519481/angular2-material-dialog-has-issues-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycomponent)

Comment: Yeah, that solved the issue - thank you! I just saw this is actually mentioned in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) (I must have overlooked it there) but I don't see that in the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) example.

Comment: FWIW, it gives you an error in the console that tells you about it when you open the dialog box and it's missing.

Comment: You sir are a legend ! Worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. Just want to add : in version 6.x.x and later, it doesn't seem to display any error about EntryComponent

Comment: @displayname I have an other issue. when open dialog it automatic closed within 1sec. and it show top to bottom as per i click. what is the actual problem?

Comment: Anyone else have this issue after upgrading to Angular 9, and their documentation saying you no longer need "entryComponents" declared?

Comment: @ymerej using angular 10 & facing this issue. have you got any workaround/solution?

Comment: @Ganesh I can't remember exactly what I did, but I think it was along creating a quick example project and comparing differences. I believe it had something do with enabling ivy engine in angular 9, that got it working...

Comment: I am getting this on ng9 and ng10 and I have Ivy enabled. I have no idea why my dialog is coming up but no angular stuff is rendered so it is empty. If I hard-code some html elements, they show but anything "angularized" is not.

Comment: But the same dialog behaves fine in other circumstances. It is only sometimes that it doesn't render and I can't figure out what causes it yet.

Comment: @crowmagnumb May I know what error you receive & is that problem occurring in production alone or in local dev also?

Comment: It works, thank you. I made sure to have declared the dialog component in declarations:[ ] and entryComponents: [ ]. More information here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-entrycomponents

Comment: @crowmagnumb Did you solve this? I am having the same issue..

Comment: @Jadamae77 Oh geez, I don't know how I didn't see Ganesh 's question above. Sorry. But to answer, yes but now I don't remember anything. Soooo much was changing in that period, I was having tons of problems and changed so many things. I don't even know if I would have recognized at the time what fixed it. :( My foggy recollection is that it ended up being something stupid on my end, but that's not much help here.  :(

Comment: @crownmagnumb totally understand...thanks for the response!

Comment: @crowmagnumb Did you find out what fixed that issue? I'm having the exact same one where the modal just shows up empty whenever I use the injected data but shows fine when hardcoding html. i tried the ngZone solution below but that didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry @ShehbanPatel as I stated I don't recall anymore, it was a long time ago.  sorry. :(

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem and solved it through **ngZone.run()** method.
I am using **Angular 13** so those **entryComponents** are not needed

So I have a page that opens a dialog (seperate compoenent) on a callback function ( like a feedback form )

But the dialog doesn't render **all the angular related components** but rendered only **Html CSS** that are written in refund-popup.component.html and refund-popup.component.css

This is because the callback comes from out of angular zone. So i am just making my dialog box run inside zone.

**Solution**

```js
import { NgZone} from '@angular/core'
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { RefundPopupComponent } from 'src/app/components/refund-popup/refund-popup.component';



@Component({
selector: 'app-create-profile',
templateUrl: './create-profile.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./create-profile.component.scss'],
})

export class CreateProfileComponent {
   constructor(private zone: NgZone , private dialog: MatDialog) {}
   
   someFunction() {
       this.zone.run(() => this.dialog.open(RefundPopupComponent}))

    }     
}
```

I have updated before and after images , after including ngZone run method

[image: Before ngZone run]

[image: After Adding ngZone]

Comment: this worked for me, but do you have any more information on why it is necessary?

Comment: In my case I am opening the component out of angular zone. So I am forcing the angular to run the change detection by using `ngZone.run()`

Answer (score 2):

with the new since 9.0 ivy Compiler the `entryComponents` field is no longer necessary and has been deprecated.

I simply fixed this issue by restarting my `ng serve`.

Comment: In my case there was a compile error that wasn't being displayed until I restarted `ng serve`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - APRIL 2021**

With Ivy, the fix for this is no longer to add your component to entryComponents. I had this issue and to make it more confusing, it worked locally running in both dev and production, but didn't work in our deployed environment. It just silently failed. After banging my head against the wall all day I discovered a circular dependency that for some reason hadn't been throwing an error. Once I removed this dependency, everything works as expected.