# How to correctly configure MatDialog?

Tags: angular

Trying to show `MatDialog` in my Angular page when the user inputs wrong username and password combination, instead I get one that shows my login page itself.
See Image below:
[Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQD0R.png)

Here is what I have tired in the LoginComponent:

```
     login() : void {
              const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
  this.utilisateurService.getLogin(this.username,this.password).subscribe((util: UtilisateurModel) => {
              this.utilisateur = util;
              if(util)
              {
                this.router.navigate(["home"]);
              }
              else
              {
                dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
                dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
                dialogConfig.data = {
                  id: 1,
                  title: 'Désolé, nom d\'utilisateur ou mot de passe non reconnu.'
              };
          this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, dialogConfig);
              }
            });

          }
```

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47241449/11084787) by adding `entryComponents` in the `@NgModule` of `app.module.ts` but with no changes:

```
     providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    LoginComponent
  ]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the problem then? Got any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line:

```
this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, dialogConfig);
```

you should pass your **another component** that says something wrong with credentials instead of `LoginComponent`. So you need to define new component specificly to display that error message, pass it to `open()` and don't forget to register it in `entryComponents`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: So do I have to design that as well?

Comment: Yeah, just new component, with simple html template of what you want to display, and that is it

Comment: Remember to add the new `NewComponent` to your entry components of the module.
You can remove `LoginComponent` from entry components.

To pass data to the new component you need to add whatever data you need using the `data` object of `MatDialogConfig`.

You can consume that data inside the new component by using an injection token `[MAT_DIALOG_DATA][1]` in its constructor. 

[1]:  https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MAT_DIALOG_DATA