# Dialog not working in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use `dialog` from the angular material. I am trying to implement the 1st example given at the page:
[Angular Material Dialog URL](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)
Here is the Stackblitz URL of the example given at the above page:
[Example Mentioned on Angular material website](https://stackblitz.com/angular/ovbokrmoajb)

The only modification I have done is I have moved the dialog component in a separate folder. But the dialog is not opening properly and no data is displayed.
Here is the Stackblitz link to my work:
[My Implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwr4p3)

I think somehow data is not getting passed in the dialog component. But I am not able to figure out why. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Stackblitz, the console displays a helpful error message after the button is clicked:

```
ERROR
Error: No component factory found for DialogComponentComponent. Did you add it 
to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

To fix this, you need to add the component that is displayed in the dialog to the entryComponents collection in app.module.ts (or the main.ts file in Stackblitz):

`entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExample, DialogComponentComponent],`

This is needed because the components displayed in the dialog are not referenced in a template via a component's selector. Since Material's dialog component references the displayed component by type, Angular needs to know that this component still needs to be loaded and not tree-shaken away during compile. [Angular docs go into some additional detail on entryComponents if you're interested](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components).

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But why do we need DialogComponentComponent as an entryComponent?

Comment: Added additional information on why this is needed.

Comment: FYI Angular 9+ no longer requires `entryComponents`.

Answer (score 2):

declare it with the enrtyComponents as well in your main.ts:

```
...
entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExample, DialogComponentComponent],
...
```

[here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519481/angular2-material-dialog-has-issues-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycomponent?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

entryComponents is not required for over version 9 of Angular.

My issue was simply the `href="#"` in my button opening the Dialog. Removed that and the issue was fixed.
Props are all due [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50727964/4179709).