# Angular Material dialog doesn't open

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a problem with dialog from angular material, when i press button to open it, it does, but not rly. Dialog does not show up but console prints 'open' and 'close', no errors

Dialog component

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {RssFeed} from "../model/rssFeed";
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from "@angular/material";
import {AppService} from "../service/app.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-feed-dialog',
  templateUrl: './new-feed-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-feed-dialog.component.css']
})
export class NewFeedDialogComponent {

  rssFeed: RssFeed = new RssFeed();

  constructor(private service: AppService,
 public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewFeedDialogComponent>,
 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
  }

  onSaveClick(): void {
    this.service.saveRssFeed(this.rssFeed)
    this.dialogRef.close(this.rssFeed);
  }

  onCancelClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

html

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>
  <mat-icon>library_add</mat-icon>
  New Feed
</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <form>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Feed Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="rssFeed.name">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Feed Url" name="url" [(ngModel)]="rssFeed.url">
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onCancelClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="onSaveClick()">Save</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

I'm opening it from another component

```
onAddRssFeedClick(): void{
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewFeedDialogComponent)
    dialogRef.afterOpen().subscribe( ()=> {
      console.log('open')
    })
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('close')
    });
  }
```

Comment: Did you add NewFeedDialogComponent to your module's entryComponents ?

Comment: @YoukouleleY I did

Comment: What exactly happens ? You see the 'close' event, then I assume the overlay appears and you can click it ?

Comment: No, nothing appears, i only click on onAddRssFeedClick() and console prints open and right after that close, nothing appears on the page

Comment: possible to upload something on stackblitz ? So far I don't see anything wrong in your code, except the `dialogRef` inside your component that has no reason to be public

Comment: Also I see you're injecting data but not providing it when you open the dialog, did you try removing the `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any`?

Comment: on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unacyk) it works just fine,

Comment: Indeed it works fine on stackblitz... it does not help us then . We must be missing something obvious, I'm going to test on my machine

Comment: It worked before so i must have changed something accidentally :|

Comment: @YoukouleleY Whole project [here](https://github.com/Kamil159/RssReader)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `app.component.html`, there is the button that triggers your modal `<a class="nav-link"  (click)="onAddRssFeedClick()" href="#">Add Feed</a>`

Remove the `href="#"` and you're good!