# Angular Material Dialog closes immediately

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I try to open a Angular Material dialog from my component. But the dialog closes immediately after it opens.

I know there are some similar questions on Stackoverflow, but their answers don't seem to work for me. Not sure if calling the dialog function out of the complete part of the subscription is the problem.

ExampleDialogComponent.ts

```
export class ExampleDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  inputVal1: string;
  inputVal2: string;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ExampleDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.inputVal1 = data.inputVal1;
    this.inputVal2 = data.inputVal2;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onCloseConfirm() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dialogRef.close({
      message: 'Confirm',
      outputVal1: this.inputVal1,
      outputVal2: this.inputVal2,
      });
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

ExampleDialogComponent.html

```
<mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>last step</ng-template>
      <mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="onCloseConfirm()">add</button>
        <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>close</button>
      </mat-dialog-actions>
</mat-step>
```

MainCompontent.ts

```
openModal() {
    this.inputs = [];
    this.http.getInputs().subscribe(
      data => {
        data.forEach(element => this.inputs.push(element));
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => {
        this.openAddDialog();
      });
  }

  openAddDialog() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.data = {
      inputValue1: 'test 1',
      inputValue2: 'test 2',
    };

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ExampleDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('Dialog was closed');
      console.log('result: ' + result);

      this.http.createResultinDB(result);
        .subscribe(subData => console.log(subData), error => console.log(error));
    });
  }

  getDeliveryPackageList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Stackblitz will be more helpful to reproduce an issue

Comment: Did you add it as an entryComponent in your module? Unless you're on Angular 9, you'll need to do that. See this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519481/angular2-material-dialog-has-issues-did-you-add-it-to-ngmodule-entrycomponent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is causing the issue:

```
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="onCloseConfirm()">add</button>
```

The `onCloseConfirm` function is getting called immediately when the dialog opens, because of how angular binding works.

You have a couple options. You can use a click handler on the button to call your function:

```
<button mat-button (click)="onCloseConfirm()">add</button>
```

You or you can continue using [mat-dialog-close], and not use your `onCloseConfirm` function:

```
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="[inputVal1, inputVal2]">add</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. <button mat-button (click)="onCloseConfirm()">add</button> worked well for me.

Answer (score 10):

For me, the source of the problem was different. I had an hyperlink with a (click) property. When I clicked on the hyperlink, the function that opened the dialog was called, but the event was propagated to the href of the `<a>` element, closing immediately the dialog after it was open. Solution was to stop the propagation.

```
<a href="#" (click)="$event.preventDefault(); aboutMyApp();">About...</a>
```

...

```
aboutMyApp() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AboutDialog, { width: '400px', height: 'auto' });
}
```

Hope this can be useful to anyone.

Comment: Thanks... this solved my issue perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have to add to your app.module.ts the `entryComponents` array with the name of your Dialog component as follow:

```
@NgModule({
  entryComponents: [
    ExampleDialogComponent
  ],
  declarations: [...],
.
.
.
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Added ExampleDialogComponent to entryCompontents and declarations, but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

removing the link solved my problem in my case, I remove link from

```
 <a class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" href="/#/home/homepage" (click)="opendialogue()" >&nbsp;Profile</a>
```

I remove unwanted link i.e. `href="/#/home/homepage"` to overcome from automatic closing of dialogue

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for Minimal, Reproducible Example.