# In angular 9 dialog material is render as blank in left end

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog, angular9

I need a help on mat dialog render on screen.
adding the steps which i followed to perform this action below.

The packages installed in the project is

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.7
@angular/cdk                      6.4.7
@angular/flex-layout              9.0.0-beta.29-7a22fba
@angular/material                 6.4.7
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.7
@schematics/angular               9.0.7
@schematics/update                0.900.7
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

**Next created login component**

html file

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
        Login 
      <span class="flex-spacer"></span>
      <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>&times;</button>
    </mat-toolbar>
```

Ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LoginComponent>) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**Then i have included in header component**

html code

```
<a mat-button (click)="openLoginForm()"><span class="fa fa-sign-in fa-lg"></span> Login</a>
```

Ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openLoginForm() {
    this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, {width: '500px', height: '450px'});
  }

}
```

**Called in app module**

```
....
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
....
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
...
  LoginComponent
  ],
imports: [
...
MatDialogModule,
  ],
 entryComponents: [LoginComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
```

The dialog comes as empty at the left corner while clicking

[image]

Also the console error is below

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttached' of undefined
    at MatDialogContainer.attachComponentPortal (dialog.js:170)
    at MatDialog._attachDialogContent (dialog.js:708)
    at MatDialog.open (dialog.js:603)
    at HeaderComponent.openLoginForm (header.component.ts:16)
    at HeaderComponent_Template_a_click_16_listener (header.component.html:8)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21693)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21742)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:934)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41264)
```

Please some one help on this issue.

Comment: Can you provide demo in the stackblitz?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i tried but not able to do it since full project is there

Comment: @Jeyasankar Have you got any workaround or solution? I'm facing the same issue after migrating from android v.8 to v.10.

Comment: I did not find any solution for this so recreated  project again.

Answer (score 1):

Add dialog component in the EntryComponents in the app.modules.ts

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with compatibility issues with Angular 9+ and older versions of Angular material like 6.4.7. I had the same problem and here is how I solved it.

1. Open package.json and change the versions of Angular Material, Angular Animations, Angular CDK and also flex-layout to the latest versions. For me, I changed to this:

```
"@angular/animations": "^10.1.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.4",
"@angular/material": "^10.2.2",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
```

2. Delete node modules folder.
3. Run `npm install` in the terminal.
4. Ensure you placed `dialogComponent` in `entryComponents`.
5. Try again, run `ng serve --open`.

This worked for me; hope it works for others.